# Julia-Lang UndefVarError: loop_inner is not defined

Tags: multithreading, julia

im trying to use Multi-Threadding (or better Multi-Processor) in Julia-Lang. Just using Base.Threads just made my Application Slower so i wanted to try Distributed.

```java
module Parallel
# ... includes ..
using Distributed
@Distributed.everywhere include("...jl") 
#... Includes Needed in Proccesses

export loop_inner
@Distributed.everywhere function loop_inner(parentValue, value, i, depth)
...
end

function langfordSequence(parentValue, depth)
    ...

    if depth < 4 && depth > 1
        futures = [@spawnat :any loop_inner(parentValue, value, i, depth)   for i = 0:possibilites]       
        return sum(fetch.(futures))
       % 2) PROBLEMATIC LINE ^^ 
    else
        return sum([loop_inner(parentValue, value, i, depth) for i = 0:possibilites]) 
       % 1) PROBLEMATIC LINE ^^ 
    end
end
end
```

But i run into
`$julia -L ...jl -L Parallel.jl main.jl -p 8`

`ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: loop_inner not defined` (At Line [see Code Above at `% 1) PROBLEMATIC LINE ^^` )

I hope someone can tell me what im doing wrong.
If im chaning `if depth < 4 && depth > 1` to `if depth < 4` im getting `UndefVarError: Parallel not defined` (At Line [see Code Above at `% 2) PROBLEMATIC LINE ^^` )

Ty in advance

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because each worker process needs to separately load your module.

Your module should look like this:

```
module MyParallel

include("somefile.jl") 
export loop_inner
function loop_inner(parentValue, value, i, depth)
end

end
```

Now you use it in the following way (this assumes that the module is inside your private package):

```
using Distributed
using Pkg
Pkg.activate(".") # or wherever is the package
using MyParallel # enforces module compilation which should not occur in parallel 
addprocs(4) # should always happen before any `@everywhere` macro or use `-p` command line option instead. 
@everywhere using Pkg, Distributed
@everywhere Pkg.activate(".")
@everywhere using MyParallel
```

Now you are ready to work with the `MyParallel` module.

#### EDIT

To make it more clear. The important goal of a module is to provide a common namespace for a set of functions, types and global (module) variables. If you put any distributed code inside a module you obviously break this design because each Julia's worker is a totally separate system process, having it's own memory and namespace. Hence the good design, in my opinion, is to keep all the *do-the-work* code inside the module and distributed computation management outside the module. Perhaps in some scenarios one might want the distributed orchestration code to be in a second module - but normally it is just more convenient to keep such code outside of the module.

Comment: hi thanks for your fast reply, my problem is that i need to call other functions from Parallel from inside loop_inner, would that be possible? loop_inner is calling langfordSequence

Comment: If they are in the same module you just call whatever you need. If they are in a separate modules you of course need to import that modules within MyParallel. With my design in each case `@everywhere using` will be just called just for the module, not for the dependencies of the module. Basically, normally `@everywhere` should never occur inside of a module.

Comment: that sounds like what i was doing anyway? i have both functions in the same module and im still getting the error

Comment: no, you had `@everywhere` inside the module and it should be outside like in my code.

Comment: so i replaced all `@everywhere` imports and  `@everywhere` functions within my `Parallel` module. Inside that module i exported `loop_inner, langfordSequence` i added your second code snippet to my "main" class to start the calculation `ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Parallel not found in current path:`

Comment: i still had to leave `using Distributed`inside my `Parallel Module` to  avoid the Programm not knowing `@spawnat` || if i replace `using MyParallel` with `include("MyParallel.jl")` and  `@everywhere using MyParallel` with `@everywhere include("MyParallel.jl")` atleast i can start the code || but i get alot of `FROM worker n: WARNING: replacing module ...` || and the programm never finishes/terminates

Comment: your module code needs to be within a private package - this `WARNING` means that it is not. https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/creating-packages/

Comment: And secondly all distributed functions should be outside of the module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217453/discussion-between-barney-stinson-and-przemyslaw-szufel).